# Difference between "link" and "website" fields for Likes

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

For the past few months I've been using the "link" field present in data returned for a Like in order to determine whether the Open Graph object being liked is part of my application. For all that time the link field contained the og:url value for the object being liked. Now the link field contains a URL for a Facebook page that is automatically created for the object being liked. I've found that sometimes the "website" field contains the og:url value for the object but sometimes the website field is not returned (even when explicitly requested).

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Did I miss an announcement from Facebook about how they are completely changing the meaning of these fields? Am I taking crazy pills? Is this just a symptom of the many current bugs surrounding like/send functionality right now? I wanted to throw this out to the community before filing a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

[Open Graph Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/)

Page Administration

To administer your page, you need to associate it with either your Facebook account or your Facebook Platform application. It is valid to associate your page with both user accounts and a Facebook Platform Application.

To associate the page with your Facebook account, add the additional property fb:admins to your page with a comma-separated list of the user IDs or usernames of the Facebook accounts who own the page, e.g.:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID1,USER_ID2"/>
```

Each listed user must click Like on the URL to be approved as an admin. This is to prevent users being made admins without their consent.

> So I think using the site url depends on the admin users liked the page or not.